# data encoding questions

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

We have `.bmp` files (2M per file) which are stored in Sybase as `long binary`. we need to retrieve them from database and send to client for display via `WebService`.

Do we have to do some encoding to pack data before we put them onto the internet?

how to choose the encoding?
thanks,

Comment: Do you want to expose it as a RESTful or SOAP service? SOAP implies some packaging, REST is more like a plain download from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Serving Bitmaps over the web is not a recommended implementation.  It would be desirable if you could convert that on-the-fly into a smaller format (GIF/JPG/PNG, depending on the content/color of the image data) and then serve that up to the user.

I currently store some images in the database and just use a simple script that sets the right Content-type header and dumps the binary out as the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress it in a data trasmission layer with Deflate or Gzip, you have implementation of it in `.NET` then you can simple do this, you must only have data in `Stream` interheited class. BMP files can get good compression rate because is a array of pixels only.